# Trying to reduce app memory, what values should I log?

Tags: android, android-memory

My app often runs out of memory. I'm working on reducing memory usage but I would like to log how much memory on average my users use, have available, etc, to see if the changes I make are having any effect on the real world.

I found these values I could capture:

```
long totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
long freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
long maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

But I'm not certain those are the right ones. Is that `freeMemory` value one that would tell me if I'm likely to get an `OutOfMemoryError`? If not, which values should I log?

Comment: you should not log anything. You should use the AS profiler tool to inspect your memory usage and where it comes from

Comment: I am using that to reduce memory usage but my app is fairly complex, it involves playing videos, has multiple webviews, etc, so recreating the environment of each user and what they are doing with the app will be very difficult if not impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that freeMemory value one that would tell me if I'm likely to get an OutOfMemoryError?

Probably not.

An `OutOfMemoryError` will occur when you try to make an allocation and there is no free block big enough to fulfill that request, even after an emergency garbage-collection run. On Android 7.1 and older, due to the nature of the garbage collector, this can occur because your heap gets fragmented. `freeMemory()` indicates the sum of all free blocks, not the size of the largest free block.

So, you need to look at the `OutOfMemoryError` crashes that you are getting. Typically, in Android, those will come from large allocations, such as loading a `Bitmap`. If that is the source of your crashes, then `freeMemory()` will be of little use, and there is nothing that you can log.

If, on the other hand, you are getting crashes for fairly small allocations (say, 128 bytes and lower), then most likely you really are exhausting your heap. In this case, `freeMemory()` may be useful to log.

Comment: The ones that I've seen are usually large allocations. I have found some bitmaps that are unnecessary that use a lot of memory but I also have other non image related stuff that uses a lot of memory. Is there a way to help with fragmentation?

Comment: @casolorz: "Is there a way to help with fragmentation?" -- don't try to keep your process around any longer than necessary, as that's the only way to defragment the heap on Android 4.4 and lower. On Android 5.0-7.1, the ART garbage collector will coalesce smaller free blocks to create larger ones, but only when your app is in the background. Android 8.0+ has a "moving" garbage collector even when your app is in the foreground. With respect to bitmaps, try to recycle them (using `inBitmap` of `BitmapFactory.Options`), so you do not need to keep re-allocating the memory.

Comment: @casolorz: Also, if the actual bitmaps are large but your use of them is for smaller `ImageViews` and the like, consider `inSampleSize` on `BitmapFactory.Options` to reduce the resolution of what you load in. You might also use `inPreferredConfig` on `BitmapFactory.Options` and try `RGB_565`, as that halves the amount of memory a `Bitmap` consumes, by reducing the color depth -- you'd need to see how well that works with your images.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I do that already for images I load with Glide, but I will look into doing it for images that are resources.

Comment: @casolorz: You do not have much control over drawable/mipmap resources. There, try to go with as low of a resolution as you can, and switch to vector drawables where practical.

Comment: Yeah I've already switched to vector where possible but have some large illustrations that don't work as vectors. So is there any other memory data I can collect from Android so I can know if my changes are actually helping my users? I would love to have a crashlytics event with the average memory usage and free memory of my users after the app has been used for a certain amount of time.

Comment: @casolorz: AFAIK, there is no API for learning more about the state of the garbage collector, such as the current largest free block. You could wrap the common crash points in your own OOM exception handler and report app-level info, such as process run time, details of your image caches, etc.

Comment: That is sort of what I've been doing for some non image related crashed. Thank you so much for the help.